# Live Nodelist vs Non-live Nodelist collections

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid, nodelist

So I am in the process of learning how to manipulate the DOM with JS and I encountered the terminologies mentioned in the subject. I understand usually with examples so I wrote some code to see the difference but they still rendered the same stuff. I want to know whether if my node is live or not is going to affect my code.

```js
//var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
//var parent = document.querySelector('ul#parent');
//var child_nodes = parent.childNodes;
//parent.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Live vs Non-live</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page">
      <h1 id="header">List King</h1>
      <h2>Buy groceries</h2>
      <ul id ="parent">
        <li id="one" class="hot"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
        <li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts</li>
        <li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>
        <li id="four">balsamic vinegar</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="js/livenonlive.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Whether I select the parent ID with getElementById or by querySelector, they still update the document and append the child li.

Comment: [*"In some cases, the NodeList is a live collection, which means that **changes** in the DOM are reflected **in the collection**"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Basically, a *live* `NodeList` does not need to be re-created (re-queried) to pick up elements added after its creation

Comment: `getElementById` and `querySelector` both return a single node, not a node list, so you can't test the difference between live and non-live node lists with those methods. What's your actual question?

Comment: @Phil ah so now I think I get it. So do you mean that even after I added code to my HTML file after I queried a nodelist, this nodelist would still pick these new elements but a querySelector would need to be created again within the script to pick up those new elements?

Comment: @AhmedMagdy exactly